# Profiling app with Cocoa Touch Framework in Instruments does not show any symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dsym, cocoa-touch

- I have an Xcode Cocoa Touch Framework project (written in
  Objective-C) that produces a `.framework` directory as well as the
  corresponding `.dSYM` file. Its using `iOS 10.1` as its Base `SDK`
  with a deployment target of `8.0`. All built using `Xcode 8.1`.
- I would like to profile my framework using Instruments so I've added
  my framework into a separate Xcode project (written in Swift). It
  builds and runs fine. However in Instruments, the symbols from my
  framework are not showing.
- In the Instruments menu: `File -> Symbols`, it shows that there are
  Missing symbols but they are all from System Frameworks
  `(/usr/lib/dyld)`

When I try to set the dSYM path to the dSYM file of my framework, it says that:

> No new libraries to symbolicate. The specified path didn't locate a dSYM for any of the selected libraries.

Am I profiling my framework the wrong way? Or am I missing other settings in my framework's build settings?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away once I profiled the app in an actual device instead of the simulator.